# Windows Server 2008 delete folder?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions

I am cleaning up some files in my web server... I came across an old Wordpress site and went to delete it. Everything went but for one theme... when I try to delete the directory I get a warning saying that I need permission from Administrators to change the folder. Mind you, I am logged in at Administrator, the only user in Administrators.

I have tried just about everything I have every heard of and still can't delete the folder. Any advice?

Comment: Since you're talking about Server 2008 I'm guessing you're on IIS? If so did you make sure the application pool was stopped? Also have you tried `rmdir` or `del` from the command prompt?

Comment: Access denied from the command prompt. IIS isn't running. I'm telling you, I have done everything I have ever even HEARD of to do. These files will not go.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the folder? Right-click on it, select Properties, then go to the Security tab. If necessary, add full permissions to your user account (or the Administrators group).

Comment: I can't change permissions... Access denied. This is the strangest thing I have ever encountered.

Comment: Who is the owner of the directory?

Comment: It seems that Administrators (group) owns the folder, but IUSR (which doesn't exist) owns the files inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the file, select Properties → Security → Advanced → Owner → Edit. Choose "Administrator" or the "Administrators" group. See if you can modify the permissions now.

If this isn't working, try to find out what process locks the file. There are many tools that can tell you that. One is ["Process Explorer" from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

If nothing else works, and you really need to delete the file, boot your machine in Safe mode and try to delete it there. Also you could try a "File Unlocker" program - won't link to one tough because that's really not the way these kind of problems should be solved...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem & I got it done by following below steps.

Right click on the folder > Properties > Security > Advanced > Now check whether your have any 'Type' column as Deny, if yes then click Change Permissions > New window opens, select the user & click Edit, provide full control > OK.

Now, delete your folder.